# Expo FCM push notification sound not working

Tags: android, push-notification, expo

I have tried this code:

```
const sendPushNotification = async (vendor_token, user_message) => {

    const message = {
        to: vendor_token,
        priority: Platform.OS === 'android' ? "normal" : "high",
        sound: "default",
        title: 'Order Detail',
        body: user_message,
        data: { data: 'goes here' },
        _displayInForeground: true,
    };
    const response = await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message),
    });
    const data = response._bodyInit;
    console.log(`Status & Response ID-> ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
};
```

But if add sound: true for Android notification not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is there a notification, but no sound? Is there no notification at all?

Answer (score 0):

const sendPushNotification = async (vendor_token, user_message) => {

```
const message = {
    to: vendor_token,
    priority: Platform.OS === 'android' ? "normal" : "high",
    sound: "default",
    title: 'Order Detail',
    body: user_message,
    data: { data: 'goes here' },
    _displayInForeground: true,
    channelId: "chat-messages",`enter code here`
};
const response = await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
});
const data = response._bodyInit;
console.log(`Status & Response ID-> ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
```

};

Just add **"channelId: "chat-messages"** in the code and android notification sound is working perfectly